# Xquery support in IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea, xquery

Has anyone had any success developing XQuery in IntelliJ?  Specifically, does anyone know of any code completion or code syntax highlighting abilities that exist already or that you've built?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [IntelliJ XQuery Support Plugin](http://ligasgr.github.io/intellij-xquery/) supports XQuery 3.0, syntax and error highlighting, keyword completion, code navigation, function and variable completion, code formatting amongst other things. It can also run XQuery against Saxon, MarkLogic, BaseX, eXist, Sedna, Zorba and Oracle XDB or any other XQuery processor which supports the XQJ standard.

Comment: Looks like the nicest, latest option.

Answer (score 3):

The best, stable option that I've used so far is [Rob Whitby's IntelliJ-Idea-Xquery](https://github.com/robwhitby/IntelliJ-Idea-XQuery) goodness.  Basic functionality: code highlighting, core api code completition, better tabbing.  Easy install (drop in config xml file)

Answer (score 0):

I use this plugin: [XQuery-IntelliJ-Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8612-xquery-intellij-plugin)

and it is quite good, as I can integrate the Saxon-HE jar file that I also use at runtime and I can run my Xqueries and see the output immediately in the console.